# Getting run-time 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed when using vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm trying to create a userform in excel using vlookup.  The userform should allow users to enter a number and it return info from other cells in the data range.
I am using the below code from a tutorial but keep getting "Getting run-time 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet'" error.
I'm new to VBA.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

'Check to see if value exists

If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("A:A"), Me.ComboBox1.Value) = 0 Then

MsgBox "Postcode not Found"
Me.ComboBox1.Value = ""

Exit Sub

End If

'Lookup values based on first control
With Me
.TextBox1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.ComboBox1), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 2, 0)
.TextBox2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.ComboBox1), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 3, 0)
.TextBox3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.ComboBox1), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 4, 0)
.TextBox4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.ComboBox1), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 5, 0)
.TextBox5 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.ComboBox1), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 6, 0)
.TextBox6 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.ComboBox1), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 7, 0)
.TextBox7 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.ComboBox1), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 8, 0)

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Apologies the error is in these 7 lines TextBox1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.ComboBox1), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 2, 0)

Comment: You can try using `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("Lookup")` instead

Comment: That worked - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### Try swapping

`Sheet2.Range("Lookup")` with `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("Lookup")`

---

Or for readability,

```
Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

With Me
    .TextBox1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.ComboBox1), ws.Range("Lookup"), 2, 0)
```